# Finding where the earliest dates in two tables are not equal

Tags: mysql, date

I have two tables, linked by an ID column. Each table has a date column, formatted as 8 numbers ie. 20230102.

My goal is simple: find the earliest date for each ID in both tables, and determine if these dates match.

Historical_Period

| ID | StartDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 18020101 |
| 1 | 19000217 |

CountryName

| ID | StartDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 15161129 |
| 1 | 20020301 |

Here is what I have tried:

> Select
> *
> from Historical_Period t1
> inner join CountryName on CountryName.ID=t1.ID
> where  CountryName.StartDate  <> (Select min(Historical_Period.StartDate) from Historical_Period) group by t1.StartDate;

The result is a mess. I neither get the earliest dates for each ID, and some of them match...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select HID, CID, Hdate, Cdate, case when Hdate <> Cdate then '!Matched' else 
'Matched' end  from
(select ID as HID, MIN(StartDate) as Hdate from Historical_Period group by 
ID) a, 
(select ID as CID, MIN(StartDate) as Cdate from CountryName group by ID) b 
where a.HID = b.CID
```